# MS Word: Adding small numbers above and below a fraction

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-word-2016, equations

How do you put a small number above and a small number below a fraction in an Microsoft-Word-equation, like in the picture below (encircled in red)?

The numbers aren't just raised/lowered in the usual way, because they appear in the center, not on the right side.

[image: Picture of the fraction]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on both the numerator and denominator to have those "holding places" to appear on the center. For example, on the image below, I have typed 2 on the numerator, then pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> and type 120. I have typed 180 on the denominator, then pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> and type 3.

[image]

To reduce the font size, select the part of the equation you want to change. Then, select "ab text" on the Conversions group found on the Equation tab. Click Home, enter the size of the font or click on Decrease Font Size button. The equation will look like this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your answer.
Do you also know how to make these numbers smaller, like in the picture?

Comment: @Koz If the answer is satisfactory, you can mark it as answered. Please visit the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Do you know how to get the numbers smaller as well? @ReddyLutanadio

Comment: @Koz See edit on how to reduce the font size.